# Is it possible to write any convergent sequence as the sum of two oscillating sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it possible to write any convergent sequence as the sum of two oscillating sequences?

Let $s_n$ be a convergent subsequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty}{s_n}=L$ for some real number $L$.

I believe what is meant by "oscillating" here is that each term of the sequence has a different sign than the previous one., e.g. 1,-2,3,-4,...

The first example I looked at was a constant sequence, say $s_n=1=\{1,1,1,...\}$ and I tried to find two oscillating sequences whose sum is $s_n$. I found the sum of $\{2,-1,2,-1,...\}$ and $\{-1,2,-1,2,...\}$  to work, so that's nice.

The next one I tried was $s_n=\frac{1}{n}=\{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,...\}$ which similarly can be represented by $s_{n_k}+s_{n_i}$ where
$$s_{n_k}=\{2, -1/2, 4/3, -1/4, 6/5,...\}$$
$$s_{n_i}=\{-1,1,-1,1,-1,...\}$$.

This seems promising, but how does one rigorously prove (if it's true) that this holds generally for *all* convergent sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for any sequence, whether it converges or not.

Given a sequence $(s_n)$, we define two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ with $a_n+b_n=s_n$, with the even terms of $a_n$ positive and the odd terms negative; and the odd terms of $b_n$ positive and the even terms negatives.

Namely, for even indices, let:
$$a_{2k}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1 & \text{if }s_{2k}=0;\\
2s_{2k} &\text{if }s_{2k}\gt 0;\\
-s_{2k} &\text{if }s_{2k}\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad
b_{2k} = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
-1 &\text{if }s_{2k}=0;\\
-s_{2k} &\text{if } s_{2k}\gt 0;\\
2s_{2k} &\text{if }s_{2k}\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$
For odd indices, let:
$$a_{2k+1}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
-1 & \text{if }s_{2k+1}=0;\\
-s_{2k+1} &\text{if }s_{2k+1}\gt 0;\\
2s_{2k+1} &\text{if }s_{2k+1}\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad
b_{2k+1} = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1 &\text{if }s_{2k+1}=0;\\
2s_{2k+1} &\text{if } s_{2k+1}\gt 0;\\
-s_{2k+1} &\text{if }s_{2k+1}\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$
Note that the terms have the signs as promised: $a_{2k}$ is always positive, $b_{2k}$ is always negative, $a_{2k+1}$ is always negative, $b_{2k+1}$ is always positive. Thus, both sequences alternate signs.

Note also that if $s_i\neq 0$, then $a_i+b_i = 2s_i-s_i = s_i$. And if $s_i=0$, then $a_i+b_i=0=s_i$. Thus, $(s_n)$ is the sum of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, with both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ oscillating, in the meaning you specified.